# Error in Hibernate 6.0.0: QueryTypeMismatchException - Specified result type [type1] did not match Query selection type [type2]

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-6.x

I'm facing an issue with Hibernate after upgrading to version 6.0.0 (it was working fine in previous versions). I have the following code snippet:

```
 CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(classe);
 Root<?> root = criteria.from(fatherClass);
 Join<?, T> join = root.join(table);
 criteria.select(join).where(builder.equal(root.get(nameField), id));
 TypedQuery<T> query = session.createQuery(criteria); // QueryTypeMismatchException
 List<T> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

When I execute this code, I receive the following error:

```
org.hibernate.query.QueryTypeMismatchException: Specified result type [com.hcf.test.entities.TestEntitiyParent] did not match Query selection type [com.hcf.test.entities.TestEntitiyChildren] - multiple selections: use Tuple or array
```

This error didn't occur in previous versions of Hibernate but started happening after the update to version 6.0.0. Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can resolve this issue in Hibernate version 6.0.0?

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If my code's intention is not clear, please note that it aims to retrieve children records associated with a parent entity.